# Should I take ownership of /media, /mnt, and /opt or join root group?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems

I am surprised that `/mnt`, `/media` or even `/opt` are not writable by myself on my own system (Linux-Ubuntu). Should I always use `sudo` for any action on these paths?

Or would it be better to add myself to the `root` group?

I guess this might be the thing to do:

```
sudo chown root:nowox /opt /mnt /media
sudo chmod u+w /opt /mnt /media
```

Comment: `man hier` will explain what are these folders for. You don't want to have world-writeable mount points and there is no reason why exactly your user would have write access to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not add yourself to the `root` group, this many have many unintended side effects granting more than you intended.

These directories are intentionally not writable by normal users.  In the event you need to make manual changes to them (which will be rare), you can perform those operations as root via `sudo`.